# Do decoy wasp nests work?

Tags: entomology, pests

Some people put up fake wasp nests in an attempt to deter real wasps from building nests nearby. According to [Do Wasp Nest Decoys Work?](https://askentomologists.com/2020/07/14/do-wasp-nest-decoys-work/):

> Wasps are unlikely to be deterred by fake nests. Although not officially studied in the scientific literature yet, wasps have been shown to make nests in close proximity and even build nests on top of old ones. Queens of one species have even been found to overwinter in the old nests of other wasp species. Best thing to do if you’re worried about wasps, is to continually monitor the areas around your house so you can address any inklings before there is a real problem.

Is there any evidence either way that’s of Skeptics SE quality?

Comment: It’s not clear if the claim in question is that they do work or that they don’t work. It seems like you’re questioning the claim that they don’t work made by Polistes fuscatus on the linked web page.

Comment: @ToddWilcox But there's no difference between "do they?" and "don't they?" as a question, is there? I have no opinion yet on their efficacy.

Comment: I know I have barely any rep here, just going off the help center: “Skeptics Stack Exchange is for challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results.” Seems like there are two possible relevant claims here that you could be questioning and I was wondering which one it was. The difference between one claim and the other is that falsifying one doesn’t necessarily confirm the other. They could both be wrong or both be right in certain ways or circumstances.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I don't understand why you think they're different questions. The answer to both is either that they are effective or they're not (or something in between). You'll find people online throwing around both answers with too little proof. (Also, I have enough rep here to hopefully know what's on topic.)

Comment: Note that your quote only claims that wasps will happily settle near or even in what they perceive to be an *empty* or *abandoned* nest. I don't know whether they make this perception based on activity of wasp or based on the status of the nest. So your quote could be true but a properly build decoy works nevertheless.